Good app for audio playback of a synced and frequently updated iCloud folder
As an amateur audio producer I like to play songs from my iPhone onto various speakers, including car speakers. I drop bounced tracks into an iCloud folder and the files end up on my phone. So far so good. I can just play open mp3 and it will play. But I have to do so one file at a time. If I'm on a drive and want to play several tracks this is not practical. I cannot find any app or way to use the iPhone music app to play back a whole folder -- UNLESS I manually add each song to the Music app playlist. I also tried using Spotify's "local file playback" option, but then it shows every mp3 on my device (some I don't even know where they are or why they're on there!). I am hoping some app could just treat an iCloud folder as a playlist. Does this exist?

I don't know an answer for this involving iCloud. But I have been experimenting with https://samply.app a little recently. It is intended for this sort of use, and has an iOS app (which admittedly, I haven't tried yet). You'd need to drop your tracks into Samply's cloud instead of iCloud. It's free, with certain limitations. Worth a look? (I'm writing this as a comment rather than an answer, because I'm not really answering the question.)
